# except column of semi structured data with bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with semi-structured data, where I need to do a select with an exception of two columns.

example:

```
select *, except(object1.address.street.value, object1.address.street.id)
FROM `project-id.dataset-id.table-id`
```

assuming my table has a struct of that type

```
select *, except(object1.address.street.value, object1.address.street.id)
FROM `project-id.dataset-id.table-id`
```

I would like to get all the columns except those two from the except

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to get all the columns except those two from the except

Since the data has a nested structure, you need to replace all the field values on the path like below.

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT STRUCT(STRUCT(STRUCT(10 AS value, 'id1' AS id, 'other' AS col1, 'another' AS col2) AS street) AS address) AS object1
)
SELECT * REPLACE((SELECT AS STRUCT object1.* 
           REPLACE((SELECT AS STRUCT object1.address.*
             REPLACE((SELECT AS STRUCT object1.address.street.*
               EXCEPT(value, id)
             ) AS street)
           ) AS address)
         ) AS object1)
  FROM sample_data;
```

**Query results**

[image]